# Why I cannot assign hexadecimal values into foo* const array[]?

Tags: c

In CCS6 I couldn't run this program properly.

```
typedef volatile struct{
    unsigned int pin_in;
    unsigned int pin_out;
    unsigned int pin_dir;
    unsigned int pin_ren;
    unsigned int pin_ds;
    unsigned int pin_sel;
    unsigned int reserved[10];
}io_hw_t;
//#define PABASE ((io_hw_t*) (0x200)) // this part is working

#define PABASE 0x200
#define PBBASE 0x220

io_hw_t *const  io[] = {PABASE, PBBASE}; // error
```

The warning I get is:

> " #145-D a value of type "int" cannot be used to initialize an entity
>   of type "io_hw_t *const "

How can I fix this ?

Comment: How about `io_hw_t *const  io[] = {{PABASE}, {PBBASE}};`

Comment: unfortunately did not work

Comment: Sorry, it's a pointer....

Comment: integers and pointers are different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provide explicit casting in initialization as:

```
io_hw_t *const  io[] = {(io_hw_t *)PABASE, (io_hw_t *)PBBASE};
```

`io` is declared as as array of `const` pointer to `io_hw_t`. So each member must be a pointer. But `PABASE` is integer constant and needs to be explicitly casted to pointer.

Alternatively you can add the casts in your macros also as:

```
#define PABASE ((void *)0x200)
```